# Join Table and Filter Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for help with the SQL filter condition. Basically I try to JOIN these two tables and filter the condition with AND and OR statement, but couldn't get the right result.
Lets me explain what I am trying to do.

I have two sample tables below:

```
Opportunity
OpptID  OpptName
1       a
2       b
3       c

Opportunity_Amount
RecID   BucketID    OpptID  Amount
1       101         1       1000
2       104         1       2000
3       101         2       1000
4       102         2       3000
5       105         1       4000
6       106         1       2000
7       103         2       2000
8       103         3       6000
9       104         3       5000
```

1) Example one -- Query...with condition provided as below

```
AND (BucketID = 101 and Amount > 1500)
AND ( (BucketID = 102 and Amount < 4000) OR (BucketID = 103 and Amount > 5000) )        

**Desired Output like this:**
OpptID  OpptName 
2       b           (because it match RecID# 4)
3       c           (because it match RecID# 8)
(However, OpptID# 1 is not in the result because the bucket 101 is less than 1500, and no other bucketIDs matched)
```

2) Query...with condition provided as below

```
AND (BucketID = 104 and Amount > 1500 OR BucketID = 104 and Amount < 6000) 
AND (BucketID = 102 and Amount > 4000)

**Desired Output like this:**
OpptID  OpptName
1       a       (match RecID# 2 and RecID# 9)
3       c       (match RecID# 2 and RecID# 9)
(Now, Oppt# 2 is not in the result because not match of the conditon)
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you work a little harder on explaining what you want to do and include the complete desired results?  Also, what SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some logical confusion between `OR` and `AND`. In both queries you say `AND (BucketID = x ...) AND (BucketID = y ...)`. How can that be possible? A single value for `BucketID` can't be 101 and 102 or 104 and 102 at the same time. Try these variations:

Query #1:

```
SELECT o.OpptId, o.OpptName
FROM dbo.Opportunity AS o
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Opportunity_Amount
    WHERE OpptId = o.OpptId
    AND
    (
      (BucketID = 101 and Amount > 1500)
      OR
      (BucketID = 102 and Amount < 4000)
      OR
      (BucketID = 103 and Amount > 5000)
    )
);
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT o.OpptId, o.OpptName
FROM dbo.Opportunity AS o
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Opportunity_Amount
    WHERE OpptId = o.OpptId
    AND
    (
      (BucketID = 104 and Amount > 1500 and Amount < 6000) 
      OR
      (BucketID = 102 and Amount > 4000)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. Maybe I need to explain it better. Sorry for the confusion. I will work on it based on your example.

Comment: @Milacay Yes, I think you do, because these solutions give exactly the results your question seems to state that you want, while I don't see how Gordon's possibly could. Nothing against Gordon's answer, but he seems to have solved a different problem that you didn't ask about.

Comment: Sorry @Aaron, after I tried your solution, it fits better. However, Gordon's solution does help me alternately.

Comment: @Milacay That's fine, and I wasn't trying to wrestle the accept away, it just doesn't seem to match the question as written.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't want a `join` at all.  I think you want a `group by` with a `having` clause.  You are looking for opportunities that meet any of your conditions.  So:

```
select oa.OpptId
from Opportunity_Amount oa
group by oa.OpptId
having sum(case when BucketID = 101 and Amount > 1500 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when BucketID = 102 and Amount < 4000 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when BucketID = 103 and Amount > 5000 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This is a bit of a guess, and I'm not sure the conditions are quite right.  But you seem to want `OpptId` where any one of these three conditions are true, and that is what the `having` clause does.

If you want the other fields, just join in to the other table.

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows that meet one of the conditions for each `OpptId`.  The `> 0` is simply saying that at least one row exists with that condition.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Sorry for that confusion.. I will try that.  BTW: what is mean "Then 1 else 0 end"?  show if TRUE or NOT show if FALSE?

Comment: Thanks again @Gordon. This should be the solution I am looking for. Basically, I have a form where user dynamically customize the filter for buckets. Looks like I find all those OpptID first, then join them back to the table I want...